# Blending 2 BGRA frames OpenCV - the output array type must be explicitly specified in function 'arithm_op

Tags: python, opencv, alphablending

I have two 4 channel BGRA images that I simply want to call `cv2.addWeighted` on.

However, running `m = cv2.addWeighted(i, 0.5, cutout, 0.5, 0)` gives me an error:

```
When the input arrays in add/subtract/multiply/divide functions have different types, the output array type must be explicitly specified in function 'arithm_op
```

I confirmed using `.shape` that they were both the same size: `(538, 1114, 4)`
Not sure what I'm doing wrong here

Comment: same `dtype` too?

Comment: and don't expect addWeighted to respect the alpha channel. it's just a fourth channel. if you need alpha blending, https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/20780

Comment: How do you want to blend the two alpha channels? You should separate the bgr and alpha channels. Then blend the bgr images separate from blending the alpha channels. Then combine the new blended alphas back into the blended bgr image.

Comment: hm I just checked the dtype. cutout is uint8 but i is int64 even though I specificed it as `i = np.ones([mask_data.shape[0], mask_data.shape[1], 4], np.uint8) * (255, 255, 255, 150)`

Comment: Basically I'm trying to use the zed object detection feature and display an image with a mask over it like in the runner example here: (https://www.stereolabs.com/docs/object-detection/). I have the mask as a gray opencv image, and I have the background image as an RGBA image. I converted the gray mask to a transparent mask and I wanted to blend the original image with the mask

Comment: Please share your input images, representative code and at least a mock-up of your expected result. Thank you.

Comment: An equal weighted (0.5,0.5) blend is just averaging the two images. Can you not simply get the average or mean image of the two or at least just do `out = 0.5*in1 + 0.5*in2`

Answer (score 1):

Get the same problem and I find the mistake I made.

```
# two images, image and image1
print(image.shape)
print(image1.shape)
print(image.dtype)
print(image1.dtype)
added_image = cv2.addWeighted(image,0.5,image1,0.1,0)
```

Then got the exact same error as above. After printing data, I found that even two images are with the same shape, they may have different dtype.

```
(5000, 5000, 3)
(5000, 5000, 3)
uint8
int32
```

All I have to do is to change the dtype for the image1, make it same dtype as image. Then blend successfully.

```
image1 = image1.astype(np.uint8)
```